# How to prevent kernel from killing my script?

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, bioinformatics, ubuntu-22.04

So I am working on Hi-C Data Analysis using 4DN Pipeline. In that there is this step to mark the PCR Duplicates. When I run the program its works and get terminated at the end stating :-

/home/ubuntu/Pipeline/docker-4dn-hic/scripts/run-pairsam-markasdup.sh: line 35: 16998 Killed pairtools dedup --mark-dups --nproc-in ${inThreads} --nproc-out ${outThreads} --output-dups - --output-unmapped - --output ${MARKED_PAIRSAM} ${PAIRSAM}

I dont know what is the issue, I read somewhere that its the kernel that's killing the script and to check dmesg file, but there is no information regarding the process in that file. So i dont know what is happening. I also read that the input file might be the issue but the input file was generated without any error.

I am running this on AWS :-
Ubuntu
256gb Ram
64 Threads

Size of input File :- 35Gb

Comment: `Killed` indicates the process received SIGKILL. The kernel doing this from out of memory is the most common reason for this, but not the only. If it was OOM, it would show in dmesg.

Comment: When i first ran this command that time i checked the dmesg as suggested and it was OOM, so i changed the instance with larger memory after that i ran this script for like 7-8 times same error but got no information in the dmseg.